# Xquery with multiple search fields

Tags: concatenation, xquery

I have the following xml-schema for a movie database:

```
<movies>
  <movie>
    <title>A History of Violence</title>
    <year>2005</year>
    <country>USA</country>
    <genre>Crime</genre>
    <summary>Tom Stall, a humble family man and owner of a 
    popular neighborhood restaurant, lives a quiet but 
    fulfilling existence in the Midwest. One night Tom 
    foils a crime at his place of business and, to his 
    chagrin, is plastered all over the news for his 
    heroics. Following this, mysterious people follow 
    the Stalls' every move, concerning Tom more than 
    anyone else. As this situation is confronted, more 
    lurks out over where all these occurrences have 
    stemmed from compromising his marriage, family 
    relationship and the main characters' former 
    relations in the process.</summary>
 <director>     
        <last_name>Cronenberg</last_name>
        <first_name>David</first_name>
        <birth_date>1943</birth_date>
</director> 
<actor>
        <first_name>Vigo</first_name>
        <last_name>Mortensen</last_name>
        <birth_date>1958</birth_date>
        <role>Tom Stall</role>
</actor>
<actor>
        <first_name>Maria</first_name>
        <last_name>Bello</last_name>
        <birth_date>1967</birth_date>
        <role>Eddie Stall</role>
</actor>
<actor>
        <first_name>Ed</first_name>
        <last_name>Harris</last_name>
        <birth_date>1950</birth_date>
        <role>Carl Fogarty</role>
</actor>
<actor>
        <first_name>William</first_name>
        <last_name>Hurt</last_name>
        <birth_date>1950</birth_date>
        <role>Richie Cusack</role>
</actor>
 </movie>
</movies>
```

I created now search fields for actors first/last_name; genre; country; year and role.

But the problem is, that it only works with the year and the genre.

If I use

1. genre or year: I get the right results
2. last_name;first_name; country; role: I get no result

I guess it has something todo with the multiple actors and multiple country elements but i couldn´t figure out how to solve it.

Here is my Xquery code:

```
xquery version "3.0";
(:  :declare namespace util="http://exist-db.org/xquery/util";:)
declare option exist:serialize "method=xhtml media-type=text/html indent=yes";

let $year := lower-case(request:get-parameter('year', ''))
let $genre := request:get-parameter('genre', '')
let $first_name := request:get-parameter('first_name', '')
let $last_name := request:get-parameter('last_name', '')
let $country := request:get-parameter('country', '')
let $role := request:get-parameter('role', '')



let $movies := collection('/db/Movie/data')/movies/movie[if(not($genre)) then xs:boolean(1) else equals(genre, $genre)][if(not($year)) then xs:boolean(1) else equals(year, $year)][if(not($country)) then xs:boolean(1) else equals(//country, $country)][if(not($first_name)) then xs:boolean(1) else equals(//actor/first_name, $first_name)][if(not($last_name)) then xs:boolean(1) else equals(//actor/last_name, $last_name)][if(not($role)) then xs:boolean(1) else equals(//actor/role, $role)]

return
<html>
<head>

     </head>
     <body>
        <h1>Search results:</h1>

        <ol>{
 for $movie in $movies
   let $title := $movie/title/text()
   let $year := $movie/year/text()
      return
                <li>{$title} ({$year})</li>



        }</ol>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!
Greets

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. In the filter predicate for last_name, you use variable $first_name. Using a bit more line-ends and whitespace might make it easier to spot such mistakes.

You can also make the predicates a bit shorter by using a smarter boolean expression. You can replace `xs:boolean(1)` by `true()`, but you can also rewrite the predicates as follows:

```
[empty($genre) or equals(genre, $genre)]
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the typo but it sill doesn´t work :( now I get also for last_name no result anymore.

Comment: @user3181473: Tried removing those // in front of //country etc yet? They are unnecessary. They shouldn't harm, I thought, but not using // is (almost) always better..